# Android App Bundle Version code suddenly very high

Tags: android, react-native, build, version

I just made a new Android bundle for my React Native app. I manually updated the version code from 90 to 91 in android/app/build.gradle, but now that I am trying to upload to Play Store, the version code is 3145819 (I expected to see 91)

build.gradle:

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 91
        versionName "4.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative57_5"
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
    }
```

I use this command to bundle:

```
./gradlew bundleProdRelease --console plain
```

Not sure why this is happening, and I definitely prefer a smaller version code (easier for users to read when reporting bugs).

Any idea what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you happen to find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not figure it out... I assume this the bundle command produces this kind of build number and we have no control over it. Anyways, no user has complained about it so far `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohhh ok I finally figured it out! No, I haven't been desperately looking for an answer for the past two years... I just somehow stumbled upon it now.

So, in `android/app/build.gradle`, there is a script that generates the bundle version code. It's calculated from the version code and the target architecture version code. For example in the [RN 0.64x template](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.64-stable/template/android/app/build.gradle#L179):

```
def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)

if (abi != null) {
  output.versionCodeOverride = defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
}
```

For me, `arm64-v8a` always seems to get used as the default when generating the version code, so I get outputs like:

```
versionCode 1 => 1003
versionCode 12 => 12003
versionCode 105 => 105003
you get the idea...
```

The calculation used to involve a much more mysterious number (`1048576` ‍♂️, see in the [RN 0.59x template](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.59-stable/template/android/app/build.gradle#L134)), which seemed arbitrary and made it quite tricky to understand how this bundle version code was generated.

Now it makes much more sense!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your `/app/build.gradle` config contains some logic that transforms the versionCode likely because you are doing app bundling.

In the current master of react-native, you can see some versioning logic [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/template/android/app/build.gradle).

Possibly your build.gradle has the same or similar logic.

Google has there explanation on versioning [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-APK-versions).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It occurred whenever I ran **./gradlew bundleRelease** and I changed

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
```

to

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
```

This function is found in **android/app/build.gradle**

I am unsure how to stop it doing it aside from changing **enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture** back to **false**

Comment: This tells the build system to output a `.bundle` rather than a `.apk`. If I recall well I first encountered this problem when I started building bundles to upload to the Play Store, so indeed changing this line to `true` was causing this problem. However, keeping it set to `false` is not a solution because we do want to build and upload bundles, not apks, so we can take advantage of bundle size optimizations and such.

Answer (score 0):

Two more years later... As mentioned by [samzmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67283598/4798464), the `versionCodeOverride` formula was changed in newer versions of React Native. Here is the specific [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e1bf515ae8e77fb24f76037d9f22e903799fb637) and [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29808) discussion.

```
 output.versionCodeOverride =
-        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
+        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
```

OP was most likely using an older version of React Native with the previous formula. Working backwards, we can see how setting `versionCode 91` becomes `3145819`.

```
versionCodeOverride = ABI * 1048576 + versionCode
3145819 = ABI * 1048576 + 91
ABI = (3145819 - 91) / 1048576
ABI = 3. <--- "arm64-v8a": 3
```

In order to get smaller version codes that make sense (human readable), you'll need to use a newer version of React Native that uses the updated formula. And you may need to use a new bundle ID, in the event that the build with version 3145819 was uploaded and deployed in the Play Store. This is because new releases must increment the `versionCode` value monotonically to protect against downgrades.

---

If this helps anyone, I stumbled upon this question while debugging my own `versionCode` issues related to 32-bit integer overflow... The [Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning#versioningsettings) state:

> The greatest value Google Play allows for versionCode is 2100000000.

Because of the `versionCodeOverride` formula in `android/app/build.gradle`, I believe we are supposed to keep `defaultConfig.versionCode < 2100000`. This effectively gives us only 6 digits to use a [version code scheme](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks#using-a-version-code-scheme) with [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/).

EDIT: The versioning seems to have changed yet again in React Native 0.72... There is no longer a `versionCodeOverride` and no effective x1000 multiplier.